# error in python AI project it shows me a error whenever i give a input from my mic it shows me that it is 'none type' not iterable

Tags: python

i have written this code but whenever I say a command which i have mentioned in the code into my mic it shows me a syntax error on line 34 (from the start of the code) it shows me: argument of type "noneType" is not iterable

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3
import pywhatkit
import datetime
import wikipedia
import pyjokes


listener = sr.Recognizer()
engine = pyttsx3.init()
voices = engine.getProperty("voices")
engine.setProperty("voice", voices[1].id)

def speak(text):
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait

def take_command():
    try:
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            voice = listener.listen(source)
            command = listener.recognize_google()
            command = command.lower()
            speak(command)

    except:
        speak("could you please repeat what you just said")
    #return command

def run():
    command = take_command()
    print (command)
    if "play" in command:
        speak("playing")
        pywhatkit.playonyt("playing")
    elif "time" in command:
        time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%I:%M:%p")
        speak(time)
    elif "hello" in command:
        speak("Hello there, how are you doing!")
    elif "wikipedia" in command:
        wiki = command.replace("wikipedia", "")
        info_output = wikipedia.summary(wiki, 5)
        print(info_output)
        speak(info_output)
    elif "joke" in command:
        joke = pyjokes.get_joke()
        speak(joke)
        print(joke)  
    else:
        speak("sorry that may be beyond my abilities at the moment")

while True:
    run()
```

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: It appears (without the trace) that "command" is None, therefore the error.